# Creating a class that runs tasks sequentially

Tags: c#, task

I was trying to implement a class that would run value returning methods sequentially. I want to be able to call same instance `RunScheduled` method from multiple threads, and scheduled tasks to execute on single thread. Any scheduled method should start executing only after previous has completed.

```cs
public class TaskSequencer
{
    public Task<T> RunScheduled(Func<T> func)
    {
        //?
    }   
}
```

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: In most cases a `Task<T>` is already effectively started. Are you sure you didn't mean to make the parameter a `Func<T>`? That would make more sense.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I edited my question accordingly.